# Maximization of distribution

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima

I would like to maximize the Conﬂuent Hypergeometric Distribution in order to apply a Rejection sampling. The formula of the distribution is

$f(x;a,b,c) = K x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}e^{-cx}$

where $0 \leq x \leq 1$ and $a,b>0, c\in\mathbb{R}$

and let us assume that K is constant in terms of x.   I would like to maximize this distribution in order to find an upper bound C and apply the rejection sampling.

Comment: All that needs doing here is differentiating and setting equal to zero, thus finding the turning point. That will give you your maximum point which acts as an upper bound. It will be in terms of $a,b,c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{d f(x)}{dx} = \left\{x^{a-2} (1-x)^{b-2} e^{-c x} \left(-a x+a-x (b+c-2)+c x^2-1\right)\right\}$$

and set to $0$ gives the real solutions:

$$x = \frac{\pm \sqrt{(a+b+c-2)^2+4 (1-a) c}+a+b+c-2}{2 c}$$

Answer (score 0):

To maximize $f(x;a,b,c)$ with respect to $x$, it suffices to maximize its logarithm. Since $K$ is constant, that means we need to maximize
$$
(a-1)\log x+(b-1)\log(1-x)-cx.
$$
You can find the stationary points by setting the derivative to $0$, i.e.
$$
\frac{a-1}{x}-\frac{b-1}{1-x}=c.
$$
If you multiply this out you obtain a quadratic equation for $x$.